# Teradata: Error 3504 and generating subset of column in Select

Tags: sql, select, case, teradata, error-code

Hi I was trying to work on a teradata sql problem where I need to exclude all saledate in Aug 2005 and calculate the daily revenue for each store/month/year combination for any stores that have no fewer than 20 sale days.

My idea is to generate a subset of the saledate column in the subquery and work with it. And here is my code.

```
SELECT Sub.store, Sub.Year_, Sub.Month_, Sub.TotalSaleDate, Sub.Daily_rev, sub.Total_rev
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN (NOT (EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate)=8 
             AND EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate)=2005)) THEN saledate END) AS 
             NewSaleDate, COUNT(NewSaleDate) AS TotalSaleDate,
             SUM(amt) AS Total_rev,
             Total_rev/TotalSaleDate AS Daily_rev,
             EXTRACT(MONTH from NewSaleDate) AS Month_,
             EXTRACT(YEAR from NewSaleDate) AS Year_, store
       FROM trnsact
       WHERE stype = 'P' AND saledate = NewSaleDate
       GROUP BY store, Year_, Month_, NewSaleDate) AS Sub
WHERE Sub.TotalSaleDate >= 20
ORDER BY sub.TotalSaledate ASC;
```

And this is my output
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmYZA.png)

Here is code from someone that worked

```
SELECT 
  sub.store, sub.year_num, sub.month_num, sub.num_dates, sub.daily_revenue
FROM (
  SELECT 
  store, 
  EXTRACT (month FROM saledate) AS month_num, 
  EXTRACT (year FROM saledate) AS year_num,
  COUNT (DISTINCT saledate) AS num_dates,
  SUM(amt) AS total_revenue,
  total_revenue/num_dates AS daily_revenue,
  (CASE 
  WHEN (year_num=2005 AND month_num=8) THEN 'cannot' ELSE 'can' 
  END) As can_use_anot
  FROM trnsact
  WHERE stype='p' AND can_use_anot='can'
  GROUP BY store, month_num, year_num
  ) AS sub
HAVING sub.num_dates >=20
GROUP BY sub.store, sub.year_num, sub.month_num, sub.num_dates, sub.daily_revenue
ORDER BY sub.num_dates ASC;
```

And his result
[Correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qaIb.png)

Apparently his Daily revenue is much higher than mine. I wonder whether it is due to I am not counting Distinct saledate in the subquery. However, I tried to add use COUNT(DISTINCT saledate) and I get no output at all, 0 row. I understand how his code works but I`m frustrated where is wrong in my code. **ESPECIALLY WHY ADDING DISTINCT GAVE ME 0 ROW, DEEPLY APPRECIATE ANYONE WHO CAN EXPLAIN...**

Comment: You don't want to use `having` in your outer query, you have no aggregation at all.  There's no point in grouping in your outer query either.  Beyond that, break it down. Does your inner query work?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply. I tested my inner query. It did not work.. I got [Error 3625] [SQLState HY000] GROUP BY and WITH...BY clauses may not contain aggregate functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select #1 agggregates by date while #2 by month, just compare the number of rows returned.

What I don't understand why both queries use that strange way to exclude dates from Aug 2005. Should be done using a simple `WHERE saledate not between date '2005-08-01' and date '2005-08-31'`

And there's no need for using a Derived Table:

```
SELECT 
   store, 
   EXTRACT (month FROM saledate) AS month_num, 
   EXTRACT (year FROM saledate) AS year_num,
   COUNT (DISTINCT saledate) AS num_dates,
   SUM(amt) AS total_revenue,
   total_revenue/num_dates AS daily_revenue
FROM trnsact
WHERE saledate not between date '2005-08-01' and date '2005-08-31'
  and stype='p'
GROUP BY store, month_num, year_num
HAVING num_dates >=20
ORDER BY sub.num_dates ASC;
```

But there's probably a large number of rows per day/month and it might be more efficient to aggregate by day first avoiding EXTRACT on all rows and the COUNT(DISTINCT):

```
SELECT -- now aggregate by month
   store, 
   EXTRACT (month FROM saledate) AS month_num, 
   EXTRACT (year FROM saledate) AS year_num,
   COUNT (*) AS num_dates, -- no need for DISTINCT anymore
   SUM(daily_amt) AS total_revenue,
   total_revenue/num_dates AS daily_revenue
FROM
 (  -- daily sales first
    SELECT 
       store, 
       saledate, 
       SUM(amt) AS daily_amt
    FROM trnsact
    WHERE saledate not between date '2005-08-01' and date '2005-08-31'
      and stype='p'
    GROUP BY store, saledate
 ) as dt
GROUP BY store, year_num, month_num
;
```

Comment: Hi dnoeth, thank you for you answer. Indeed EXTRACT is a weird way of excluding dates. I used it at beginning then it didn`t work. I guess I was just stubborn trying to figure out a way to make it work. Anyway, your solution is much more self-explanatory and easy to write. As a sql beginner, I think I still need to learn how to design the logic better. Nevertheless, can you explain why when I add DISTINCT to my query I got 0 row output? Thanks again.

Comment: You GROUP BY saledate and then `COUNT(DISTINCT saledate)` always returns 1, which is way less than 20 :-)